# With MQTTLibrary for Robot Framework, is it possible to determine the exact topic of a received message?

Tags: robotframework, mqtt

I'm a new Robot Framework user, and I've added the MQTTLibrary.

I can set up a subscription as per the documentation, and successfully receive messages. It's also possible to subscribe to wildcards, e.g.

```
${message}=  Subscribe  topic=test/mqtt_test/+  qos=1  timeout=2
```

The above will successfully pick up messages published to test/mqtt_test/apples, test/mqtt_test/oranges, test/mqtt_test/pears etc.

However, ${message} appears to only contain the content of the message payload, and I've been unable to work out if it's possible to determine the exact topic of the received message.

Can this be done with MQTTLibrary?

=============

Additional details (to provide an answer to ILostMySpoons's comment):

Sure - it's basically just the message content. So if I use...

```
mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -t test/mqtt_test/apples -m "Hello to you"
```

...and my robot framework script does...

```
Log to console  ${message}
```

...I see...

```
['Hello to you']
```

The debug output from the mosquitto broker (mosquitto -v) doesn't show message payloads but it does show the full topic path of test/mqtt_test/apples.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of `${message}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a deeper look into the MQTTLibrary and have come up with a solution. I'm both a Robot Framework and Python noob, so this may not be the best/most appropriate implementation, but it seems to work.

On my installation, the MQTTLibrary source is contained in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MQTTLibrary. Everything of interest is in the MQTTKeywords.py file.

In the _on_message_list() function, change...

```
    self._messages.append(message.payload)
```

...to...

```
    self._messages.append([message.topic, message.payload])
```

Use the Subscribe keyword in your Robot Framework script as before, but you'll now have a list of lists; specifically each entry in the list will be a list of [topic, payload]. E.g.

```
  ${messages}=  Subscribe  topic=test/mqtt_test/+    qos=1  timeout=20  limit=0
  ${third_message}= Get From List   ${messages}         2
  ${topic}=         Get From List   ${third_message}    0
  ${payload}=       Get From List   ${third_message}    1
  Log to console  \nTopic:\n${topic}
  Log to console  \nPayload:\n${payload}
```

The above example assumes that at least 3 messages were received during the 20 second timeout window.

Note that this change would break existing scripts, so a more complete solution would perhaps need to add new keywords (e.g. Subscribe And Get Topics), with additional work to ensure Subscribe still returns just the payloads.